# Azure Service Bus: Message size, technology limit and pricing

Tags: azure

I am trying to read the Azure Service Bus queue tech specs and pricing but it is not clear to me that

1) Is there any size limit for a message?

2) Is it possible that pricing is not depend on the message sizes? It seems, but I can not believe.

(I would like to send approx 10K - 100K data per message. Message queue will be consumed by concurrent identical worker roles running in multiple instances.

Thx in advance

Comment: This question can be answered with a simple google search for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas. Repeating that information here isn't much use when it changes

Comment: I am not sure it was almost a decade ago...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1-)

> Service Bus queues support a maximum message size of 256 KB (the
> header, which includes the standard and custom application properties,
> can have a maximum size of 64 KB). There is no limit on the number of
> messages held in a queue but there is a cap on the total size of the
> messages held by a queue. This queue size is defined at creation time,
> with an upper limit of 5 GB.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/

2-)

```
Queues and Topics

$0.01 for every 10,000 messages

Messages exceeding 64KB in size will result in an additional message being charged for every 64KB in message. Billable messages include any “no message available” replies from Service Bus in response to receive requests made against empty queues/subscriptions.

Relay

$0.10 for every 100 relay hours

$0.01 for every 10,000 messages

Relay hours start when the first listener connects to a given relay address and end when the last listener disconnects from that address, and are rounded up to the next clock hour. As with queues/topics, messages greater than 64KB in size will generate additional billable messages per 64KB of additional content.
```

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/

Comment: This is not quite accurate in 2017. I cant see any info about messages exceeding 64KB

Comment: This answer came from the official doc that was available in 2014.

Comment: Looks like premium level can handle messages of upto 1Mb now, albeit at a price. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging.

Comment: Does it mean that all messages are kept in 'topic' so that 'subscriptions' can have an unlimited number of messages?

Comment: I don't know about subscriptions limitations, but yes, a message lives in a topic and multiple consumers can subscribe to a topic

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Hey. Sorry to bother you after all these years, but is it possible that you could change Kb to KB? When you google the max message size for service bus it claims in huge bold letters that it's 256 Kb when it's actually 256 KB. Minor typo, but it could lead to confusion for people just googling the answer now.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I've edit it even tough I'm not sure if this answer is still valid